# Notebook output behaving erratically

Tags: notebooks, output-formatting

Normally, when reevaluating a cell, the following output cell is overwritten with the new result. I have a lengthy notebook in which at some point for unknown reasons each reevaluation generates a new output cell. I have no clue how to stop this - I think it has to do with the option `OutputAutoOverwrite`, but setting this to True does not help. Any clue on how to reset the behaviour of the notebook to the default?

After experimenting more the situation gets even worse: If I set both `CellAutoOverwrite` and `OutputAutoOverwrite` to `True`, reevaluating expressions overwrite now the following output cell. But if there is a text cell following the output cell, the text cell gets overwritten with the revised output cell! And if there is a subsection cell following the output cell, the output cell is deleted, but the new output cell is placed after the subsection cell...

Found the reason now for this strange behaviour: All text cells and subtitle cells had received the option `CellAutoOverwrite->True`. By manually changing this to `False` (but leaving `OutputAutoOverwrite` to `True`), the notebook behaves now again normally.

Comment: Sometimes I noticed what you've said. But a concrete example would be more welcome.

Comment: Where do I change these parameter settings?

Answer (score 1):

OP found the answer but didn't post it:

> Found the reason now for this strange behaviour: All text cells and subtitle cells had received the option `CellAutoOverwrite->True`. By manually changing this to `False` (but leaving `OutputAutoOverwrite` to `True`), the notebook behaves now again normally.